# HTML form definition insert to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I've created HTML form, after clicking submit button all values are stored in *MySQL* database.

I want to create ability to edit form. I'm thinking about after clicking `Edit` button form should be opened exactly the same as new form, just with all filled values whose were inserted to database.

How can I achieve that? I thought something like to store HTML code with values to database (from `<form>` to `</form>`), but I don't know If It is good idea and It is possible at all.

My real form have over 100 fields, but simplified It looks like:

**HTML form:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Add Record Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstName">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastName">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="emailAddress">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP code to insert to database:**

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['firstname']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lastname']);
$email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);

// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email_address) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email_address')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. You have to fetch all data on click of edit and then fill in to form. take a look at this tutorial - http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/php-crud-tutorial-part-3/

Comment: Also, read up on prepared statements when using PHP's modern connection methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by querying all the values from the database:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from persons WHERE UserId = '$UserId'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $first_name = $row['first_name']);
  $last_name = $row['last_name']);
  $email_address = $row['email_address']);
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Then `echo` in the `value` attribute:

```
<label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstName" value=<?php echo $first_name ?>">

<label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastName" value=<?php echo $last_name ?>">

<label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="emailAddress" value=<?php echo $email_address ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but how can I set these variables? Something like? `$last_name = "SELECT LastName FROM Table WHERE UserId = $UserId`

Comment: @Infinity Updated post to include querying, hope that it would help you! :)